# Client Java program to reach internet through proxy using kerberos/Keytab authentication

Tags: java, keytab

I develop a POC to do exactly what's mentionned in this topic's title.
For this, I've found [jumarko sample](https://github.com/jumarko/kerberos-auth-example) which is working perfectly. Many thanks to him for this sample :).
However jumarko's sample uses `callbackhandler` implemetation. Which is a login/password authentication.
In my case, I'd like to use a **keytab authentication** instead of.
Could someone advise which interface or which system.property should I use to get **keytab authentication**  ?
Many thanks in advance for your kind assist,